# new Socket(...).getOutputStream().isAvailable() - Проверка доступности выходящего потока

Tags: java, сокет, клиент-сервер

После того, как к серверу присоединяется клиент, то, через 10 секунд ему отправляется строчка "Hello". Но в течение 10 секунд клиент может отсоединиться, и, программа может выдать ошибку при отправлении строчки. Как предусмотреть ошибку так, чтобы перед отправлением строчки программа проверяла, не отсоединился ли клиент, или доступен ли `OutputStream` сокета?

```
String i1 = "Hello";
try {
    Socket i2 = new ServerSocket(12345).accept();
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
    i2.getOutputStream().write(i1.getBytes());
    i2.close();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: единственный правильный способ проверить, что клиент не отвалился - послать ему сообщение и дождаться ответа.

Comment: К сожалению, в роли клиента уже запрограммированный "робот". Переделать его нельзя.

Comment: тогда "послать и надеяться"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте проверку:

```
if (i2.isConnected()) {
    i2.write(i1);
}
```